# Finding the class for method

Tags: abap

How do you actually find the class for a specific method in ABAP? Is this even possible?

EDITED: I was given a method name without the class name from the functional team, so I am wondering if we could find the class with the given method name.

Comment: How is the method being called?  Can you give an example in your question?  I could better answer if so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "finding the class for a specific method in ABAP".

- If you want to find out which class implements a certain method of an interface at design time, use the SE80 to find the implementing classes of the interface. If that doesn't suit your needs, take a look at the view VSEOMETHOD and filter by REFINTNAME (referred interface name) and REFCMPNAME (method name)
- If you want to find all classes that implement a method named FOO at design time, you can also use VSEOMETHOD.
- If you want to find out which class you're calling into at runtime, use the debugger :-)
- If you need to do this programatically, there's probably something wrong with your program structure. Still it's possible using RTTI - take a look at CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR and its descendants.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

Call transaction se80 and navigate to Repository Information System (or se84 directly)

Open **Class Library**, then **Methods**. Done.

[image]

This way, you'll get all the classes thah have a method like that, and you can also specify some selection criteria there.